# Can't able to import json data from file by Logstash

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to import JSON data from my log file `mylogs.log`. Following is my logstash config file.

```
input {
    stdin { }

    file {
        codec => "json"
        path => "/logs/mylogs.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "jsonlog"
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }

    file {
        path => "/logs/out.log"
    }
}
```

After executing this config file, if I passed any JSON data it's getting parse & sending to Elasticsearch instance. I can see from Elasticsearch instance. But, whatever data exist in log file those not get imported by logstash.

Also, when I manually adding JSON data which getting parse by Logstash & send Elasticsearch instance... those data also not gettign logged in my OUTPUT file.

Don't know what is the issue.

My sample JSON data which I'm using.

```
{ "logger":"com.myApp.ClassName", "timestamp":"1456976539634", "level":"ERROR", "thread":"pool-3-thread-19", "message":"Danger. There was an error",  "throwable":"java.Exception" }
{ "logger":"com.myApp.ClassName", "timestamp":"1456976539649", "level":"ERROR", "thread":"pool-3-thread-16", "message":"I cannot go on", "throwable":"java.Exception" }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after making following modification file path plugin in Lagstash config file it's working now.

```
input {
    stdin { }

    file {
        codec => "json"
        path => "/home/suresh/Desktop/tools/logstash-5.1.1/logs/mylogs.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "jsonlog2"
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }

    file {
        path => "/home/suresh/Desktop/tools/logstash-5.1.1/logs/out.log"
    }
}
```

But, I'm getting an error of `"tags" => [
        [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ]`

Response from Console-

```
{
          "path" => "/home/suresh/Desktop/tools/logstash-5.1.1/logs/mylogs.log",
    "@timestamp" => 2016-12-27T09:56:08.854Z,
         "level" => "ERROR",
        "logger" => "com.myApp.ClassName",
     "throwable" => "java.Exception",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "BLR-SOFT-245",
        "thread" => "pool-3-thread-19",
       "message" => "Danger. There was an error",
     "timestamp" => "1456976539634",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ok. Got it!!! By removing ```json``` filter from config file ```_jsonparsefailure``` it has fixed.  :)